# Existence, but not uniqueness on point of least norm in the Banach space $(\mathbb{R^2,|| \cdot ||_1})$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Consider the Banach space $(\mathbb{R^2,|| \cdot ||_1})$, where $||x||_1=|x_1|+|x_2|$. 
 I would like to show that for any closed convex subset $K$ of $(\mathbb{R^2,|| \cdot ||_1})$ there is a point which has minimum norm. 
 I know that this is true in general, as long as the space is a Hilbert space, and in that case we have uniqueness as well. 
 However, the space in question is not a Hilbert space, as the inner product arising from the norm $|| \cdot ||_1$ does not satisfy the parallelogram law. So we might still expect existence, but not uniqueness.

 How is this proved? What would be an example for showing uniqueness does not hold?

Comment: Hint: the map $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R, x\to \|x\|_1$ is continuous. Try to find a compact subset of $K$, where you can find a minimum of $f|_K$.

Comment: Existence shouldn't be difficult at all.  Please show your effort.

Comment: For the lack of uniqueness, you can take the "unit square" $\{(x, y), ||(x, y)||_1 \leq 1\}$ and displace it by $(1,1)$. It'd be clearer with a graph which is why I'm not putting it in an answer because I don't quite know how to do that, but the lower-left side will be all the points of minimum norm, norm $1$, of that convex.